# iOS 14: How do I scan/check my vaccination QR code without a redirect to Apple's Health app page?

Tags: ios, camera, scanning

Scanning the QR code in the default iOS camera app redirects to Apple's Health App webpage instead of properly opening the link contained in the code. Worse, it doesn't provide any option to scan/open the QR code.

As I understand, the QR code is supposed to contain a link that verifies my vaccination status. I want to scan the QR code and open that link directly, skipping the redirect.

There are supposedly "SMART QR code readers" that can read these, so the format obviously isn't proprietary to Apple.

I'd prefer to do this without third-party apps if possible. I'm aware of other questions that have been asked similar to this, but all of them seem to use third-party apps.

Comment: *By definition* Apple's health app is not a 3rd party app, it's a first party app and as such is a part of iOS and handles such requests the way you are seeing it. You may need a 3rd party QR code scanning app if you object to Apple handing health related QR codes with its own Health application.